# Android MediaPlayer not working after multiple starts

Tags: android

I am having trouble with MediaPlayer. In the enclosed code, when a button is touched, a voice cue is activated when the option to do so is selected.  However, the voice works for approximately 31 times and then the sound goes off.  Using the .release() method (which I have commented out for now) causes the sound to not work at all.

How can I correct this function?

### Thank You

```
.... 
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
....
MediaPlayer mp = null;
........

//  Causes the name of the appropriate cell to be announced

    public void sayCellName() {
        if(voiceChoice == false) return;
        else{
            switch(cellName){             
            case 1:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.poly);
                break;
            case 2:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lymph);
                break;
            case 3:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mono);
                break;
            case 4:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.eo);
                break;
            case 5:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.baso);
                break;
            case 6:
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.band);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            } // end switch statement
        } // end else statement;
        mp.start();
//      mp.release();
    } // end of sayCellName
} // end of main
```

Comment: `start` isn't blocking, so you shouldn't call `release` directly after `start`. Add an `onCompletionListener` where you call `release`.

Answer (score 1):

The Android OS has a hard-coded limit of audio track resources that may play back sound simultaneously. As it so happens that limit is [32 tracks that have to be shared](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/_tmA8DRg8q4) by all running applications. What you are doing is wasting these tracks by creating fresh `MediaPlayer`s on each button click without releasing them.

For your scenario you should probably create and reuse a single `MediaPlayer` instance and release it when your `Activity` stops. It is possible to [reset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#reset%28%29) a `MediaPlayer` and [set a different stream data source afterwards](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29).

Answer (score 0):

You have to release the player OnPause or OnDestroy method.

```
   @Override
   public void onPause() {
       if (mp!= null) mp.release();
   }
```